# url codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem making a url in Codeigniter. The url is 
**mywebsite.com/users/mike** 
where *mike* is the parameter for method users. I want to delete the method users so the url becomes 
**mywebsite.com/mike** as in facebook.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use CI's routing capabilities, for example:

`$route['([\w]+)'] = "users/$1";`

Note: This may be a little tricky as you'll have to deal with routing to the other controller as well (you'll have to tailor the regex a little). I don't have CI installed to test it, so you'll definitely want to modify it.

Read more on CI routing [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure i understand what you are trying to do, but could you use mod_rewrite to prettify the urls?
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html